# How to define a grid's content as a resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a grid and want to change its content in different conditions.

So I defined some resources:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <StackPanel x:Key="MyStackPanel1">
        <!--Content-->
    </StackPanel>      

    <StackPanel x:Key="MyStackPanel2">
        <!--Content-->
    </StackPanel>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And I have the grid:

```
    <Grid Name="MyGrid">

    </Grid>
```

Now when I want to use those resources in the grid

```
 var myStackPanel = this.Resources["MyStackPanel1"] as StackPanel;
 MyGrid.Children.Add(myStackPanel);
```

I get this error:

> Element is already the child of another element.

How to change MyGrid's content in different conditions? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do that is rather to use `Templates`

Example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

  <ControlTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <StackPanel >
        <!--Content-->
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>  

  <ControlTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <StackPanel >
        <!--Content-->
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate> 

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And instead of a `Grid` as a container, use a plain `Control`:

```
<Control x:Name="MyControl" />
```

As a result you can easily switch its contents by changing its template:

```
var myTemplate = this.Resources["Template1"] as ControlTemplate;
 MyControl.Template = myTemplate;
```

Depending on your needs, you can use for that `DataTemplateSelector`s to dynamically select the appropriate template. If you need more than one `StackPanel` inside, you can just use an `ItemsControl` and play with each individual template